# How to add objects in an InfoWindow making it larger

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, infowindow

I need to have a `Button` and a `ProgressBar` in the `InfoWindow` of my markers. I have two main problems that are:

1. The `InfoWindow` is not large enaugh to contain the text I need.
2. I don't know how to add any kind of object inside `InfoWindow`.

Here is how it looks like in my map and the code I use to generate a marker:

[image: My Map]

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(enemy.position).title("Mostro " + enemy.nome).snippet("Livello " + enemy.level + "\n" + enemy.health());
map.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

As you can see the rest of the text I wrote in the snippet isn't shown.

How can I solve these two problems? 
Thank you in advance for your patience and consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom layout for info window as shown below and initialize your infowindowadapter with this layout:

********InfoWindow********

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/location_tv"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="BluePearl Veterinary Partners"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="@color/about_color"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_below="@+id/location_tv"
                android:id="@+id/direction_layout"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">



            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/direction_imageview"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_place" />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/address_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:text="1 West 15th Street, New York, NY, 10011"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/direction_imageview"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/location_tv"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
            />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:id="@+id/phone_layout"
                android:layout_below="@+id/direction_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/phone_imageview"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/direction_imageview"
                    android:src="@drawable/phone_red" />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ph_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:text="212-924-3311"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/phone_imageview"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/address_tv" />

        </LinearLayout>




        <View
                android:layout_below="@+id/phone_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>



    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

********InfoWindow.kt********

```
class InfoWindow(private val context: Context) : GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    override fun getInfoWindow(marker: Marker): View? {
        return null
    }
    override fun getInfoContents(marker: Marker): View {
        val view = (context as Activity).layoutInflater
            .inflate(R.layout.info_window_map, null)
        val location_tv = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.location_tv)
        val address_tv = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.address_tv)
        val phone_tv = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ph_tv)
        val directoryModel = marker.tag as HospitalsList?
        if (directoryModel != null) {
            location_tv.text = directoryModel.title
            address_tv.text = directoryModel.address
            phone_tv.text = directoryModel.contactnumber
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

********MapActivity.kt********

in your MapActivity where you are initilizing your map fragment use these line of code:

```
val customInfoWindow = InfoWindow(this)
   map.setInfoWindowAdapter(customInfoWindow)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! There is only one (maybe stupid) thing that I don't understand: how can I create a custom layout?

Comment: just create a new layout resource file under layout folder in android studio and paste the XML code from my answer and make changes as you need. And if it answers your question completely do accept my answer.

Comment: Ok now I have the InfoWindow I want, but it is just too big. Another problem is that I can't click the button because it seems I click the Infowindow instead. How can I fix?

Comment: 1) You can always adjust height &  widht of infowindow.xml according to your needs.

2) You can use infowindow click listener it self to achieve desired results. As documentation says you can not access views inside your infowindow. [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows) 

3)Luckily I got to know someone wrote a library to address this problem, you can have a look [Here](https://github.com/Appolica/InteractiveInfoWindowAndroid)